# ffmpeg not detecting corrupt video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file with duration 2:06:43. The video can be played for 2 hours on vlc player, but as it reaches to 2:03:00 vlc player just skips to the end of duration. I assume reason for this behavior is  corrupt video file.

I am trying to detect error in video file using ffmpeg using below command

```
ffmpeg -v error -sseof -60 -i source.mp4 -f null - 2>error.log
```

but no error log is generated for video file. is there any way I can detect these errors.

**EDIT**
tried running with warning and it produced below output

```
ffmpeg -v warning -sseof -60 -i source.mp4 -f null - 2>error.log
```

> Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it. Finishing stream
>   0:1 without any data written to it. Output file is empty, nothing was
>   encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Comment: Where are you setting file descriptor `10` used in the redirection? `ffmpeg` outputs to stderr so try with `2`.

Comment: sorry, mistakenly I have added 10. I have tried with 2 only, it's not working

Comment: try with warning verbosity

Comment: Please see the question, tried with warning too.